# How to make view source code in single line

Tags: 7, hooks

Is there any way to show rendered HTML in single line when you view source it in Drupal?

You may see in some websites like facebook.com. So, when you view source the entire HTML will be in single line, so that people can not read easily (though they can use firebug to investigate).

Comment: Isn't that just a case of minifying the request response? Rather than really obfuscating the code.

Comment: Nope, we can minify JS and CSS but not the rendered HTML...

Comment: I didn't say it was an actual Drupal option, just trying to understand your question.

Comment: Yes, I want to minify, is there any possibility?

Comment: If you are on an Apache server, mod_pagespeed is an option. If that is not available, you can try the [Minify HTML module](https://www.drupal.org/project/minihtml).

Answer (score 0):

A couple modules you might find interesting.

https://www.drupal.org/project/minify

https://www.drupal.org/project/minihtml

Comment: Nice module., but the module is minifying from $content. Not from the <head> tag.